# Passing nested params from create in redirect to show of nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, rails-routing

I have a schema like:

- Company belongs to Users (devise)
- Quote belongs to Company
- Employees belong to Company

I have a simple_form_for using cocoon to create Company & Quote & Employees from the create action in the Company controller, all objects being created just fine by the create method. But on .save of these objects I am trying to redirect to Quotes#show of the quote created by Companies#create but I'm having trouble getting the quote_id over to Quotes#show.

Can you help me understand how to get the right params over to succesfully redirect? Thanks.

companies.rb

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy ]

 def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.quotes.build
    @company.employees.build
  end

  def create
    @company = current_user.companies.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
      redirect_to company_quote_url(@company.id), notice: 'Quote request created'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:co_name, :co_number, :postcode, :industry,
    :quotes_attributes =>       [:id, :lives_overseas, :payment_frequency],
    :employees_attributes =>    [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :gender, :date_of_birth, :salary, :_destroy] )
  end
end
```

quotes.rb

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @quote = @company.quotes.find(params)
  end
end
```

routes

```
           quotes_show GET    /quotes/show(.:format)                         quotes#show
            quotes_index GET    /quotes/index(.:format)                        quotes#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
          company_quotes GET    /companies/:company_id/quotes(.:format)        quotes#index
           company_quote GET    /companies/:company_id/quotes/:id(.:format)    quotes#show
       company_employees GET    /companies/:company_id/employees(.:format)     employees#index
        company_employee GET    /companies/:company_id/employees/:id(.:format) employees#show
               companies GET    /companies(.:format)                           companies#index
                         POST   /companies(.:format)                           companies#create
             new_company GET    /companies/new(.:format)                       companies#new
            edit_company GET    /companies/:id/edit(.:format)                  companies#edit
                 company GET    /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#show
                         PATCH  /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#update
                         PUT    /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#update
                         DELETE /companies/:id(.:format)                       companies#destroy
                    root GET    /                                              companies#new
```

error message

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :company_id=>65, :controller=>"quotes"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I can't see how to get the quote_id route accross from Companies#create over to Quotes#show. When I run the redirect like; `redirect_to company_quote_url(company_params)` the error shows the header params being passed like this, i.e. this is what's available;

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", "co_name"=>"acme1", "co_number"=>"12345678", :controller=>"quotes",

"employees_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"brian", "last_name"=>"blessed", "email"=>"brian@test.com", "gender"=>"m", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"2001", "date_of_birth(2i)"=>"6", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"28", "salary"=>"10000", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "industry"=>"financial_services", "postcode"=>"al8 8ba",

"quotes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"lives_overseas"=>"true", "payment_frequency"=>"annually"}}} missing required keys: [:company_id, :id]
```

I've played and failed with different variations of;

- (params[:company][:quote_attributes[:id]])
- (@company.quote.id)

yet i just can't seem to get it right, can anyone help please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *company* `has_many` *quotes*, you should track the **latest quote for that company** and redirect to that show view of the quote.

```
def create
  @company = current_user.companies.new(company_params)

  if @company.save
    @quote = @company.quotes.last
    redirect_to company_quote_url(@company,@quote), notice: 'Quote request created'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

`last` will give you the **latest record** with the help of `created_at`

Also you should tweak your `quotes#show` like below else it will error out.

```
def show
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @quote = @company.quotes.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: @jbk My mistake, `company_quote_url` should be `quote_url` or use `company_quote_url(@company,@quote)`

Comment: @jbk Use `company_quote_url(@company,@quote)` and in the `quote#show` method define `@company` as `Company.find(params[:company_id])`

Comment: Thank Pavan, it all routes properly now . Is there a better way of doing this I wondered, it just seems this passing and defining both `@company` as well as `@quote` variables back and forth could be a bit verbose. But i guess if one's dependant and routes to the other there's no way around it?

Comment: @jbk Thats the way you have to do it. Instance variables(`@company` and `@quote` here) won't be available across the controllers unfortunately :)